# sml foldl explanation/trace

Tags: sml, fold

I'm trying to figure this out for some time but I'm not successful.
How is following function (powerset) proceeding in detail, taking the example input argument of [1,2,3]?
Thank you much for help.

fun ps L = foldl (fn (x,tl) => tl @ map (fn xs => x::xs) tl) [[]] L;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the function correctly, you have to assume there is no duplication in input lists.

The function can be understood as follows:

- We start with an accumulator which is a set of sets only consisting of an empty set (`[[]]`).
- In each step, we take every set in the accumulator, add the current element `x` to them and add these results to the accumulator.
- The final result is a set of all possible sets of `n` elements i.e. *powerset*.

To be easily express traces, let's create an auxiliary function `f`

```
fun f (x, tl) = tl @ map (fn xs => x::xs) tl
```

Now we have a trace for `[1, 2, 3]`:

```
   ps [1, 2, 3]

~> foldl f [[]] [1, 2, 3] (* Step 1 *)
~> foldl f (f (1, [[]])) [2, 3]
~> foldl f ([[]] @ map (fn xs => 1::xs) [[]]) [2, 3]

~> foldl f [[], [1]] [2, 3] (* Step 2 *)
~> foldl f (f (2, [[], [1]])) [3]
~> foldl f ([[], [1]] @ map (fn xs => 2::xs) [[], [1]]) [3]

~> foldl f [[], [1], [2], [2, 1]] [3] (* Step 3 *)
~> foldl f (f (3, [[], [1], [2], [2, 1]])) []
~> foldl f ([[], [1], [2], [2, 1]] @ map (fn xs => 3::xs) [[], [1], [2], [2, 1]]) []

~> foldl f [[], [1], [2], [2, 1], [3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2, 1]] [] (* Step 4 *)

~> [[], [1], [2], [2, 1], [3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2, 1]] (* Final result *)
```

Comment: Thank you much for taking your time, Pad!